# start countdown without any events

Tags: countdown

I have this script for countdown I wanted it to start as soon as the page loads (ideally i wanted it to run continuously since it is repeating in intervals).
when I call any function such as [startCountdown()] or [ countdown.start($('#countdown_clock').val());] I keep getting the same error [Uncaught ReferenceError: countdown is not defined]

here is the whole function 

 `window.onload = function mainCountdown() {`

```
             var countdown = Tock({
            countdown: true,
            interval: 250,
            callback: function () {
               // console.log(countdown.lap() / 1000);
                $('#countdown_clock').val(countdown.msToTime(countdown.lap()));
               // countdown.start($('#countdown_clock').val());
            },
            complete: function () {
               // console.log('end');
               // alert("Time's up!");
               repeatCountdown();
               console.log('alarm');
            }
        });

        $('#startCountdown').on('click', function () {
            countdown.start($('#countdown_clock').val());
        });

        $('#pauseCountdown').on('click', function () {
            countdown.pause();
        });

        $('#stopCountdown').on('click', function () {
            countdown.stop();
        });

        $('#resetCountdown').on('click', function () {
            countdown.stop();
            $('#countdown_clock').val('00:10');
        });
        function repeatCountdown() {
            countdown.stop();
            $('#countdown_clock').val('00:10');
             countdown.start($('#countdown_clock').val());
        }
        function startCountdown(){
            countdown.start($('#countdown_clock').val());
        }
    }
```

**How can I start the countdown without any button events.**

Thank you in advance

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry there were some other errors with the script above here's the working version.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few syntax issues that might be causing the problem.  First, I'd call the window load event like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // functions, etc here
});
```

Then, inside the window load event, you can create your timer like this:

```
var countdown = new Tock(...
```

You were missing the 'var' and 'new' keywords.  You might want to revisit the Tock documentation to make sure everything else was correct, too.

Comment: Thanks Nate just re-edited the code but still having the same problem ...I will try your suggestion just now.

Comment: already added in the script $(window).load(function () { somehow is not showing in the original question ...still not starting the countdown on page load.

Comment: You're  using "Tock" from Github, right? I'm looking at the documentation: https://github.com/Falc/Tock.js/tree/master

Comment: Yes that's the one .

Comment: You use callbacks called "callback" and "complete", but I don't see those in the documentation.  Looks like "Tock" expects you to use "onComplete", and there are several other events, too: onTick, onStart, onStop, onReset.  I think you need to revise your code to reflect those callbacks, and not the ones you're trying to use.

Comment: Thank you very much Nate for your help as a matter of fact the script drove me crazy however I found what I am looking for and much more versatile. for anyone who is looking for a simple perpetual countdown and also runs even the page is not on ...I just added the loop http://jsfiddle.net/V2S9d/659/

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)